# dynamic mapping

Tags: solidity

I would like to delete a mapping and create an other one after some point.(Basically when the contract has reached its goal and it's time to start an other cycle and i don't want to iterate through all the mapping to reset each member of the mapping one by one).I found this way :

```
contract Mapping {
mapping (uint256 => uint256) public map;
// workaround because i can't find a way to directly access to the map on contract MyContract
function write(uint256 index, uint256 data) public {
map[index] = data;
}
}

contract MyContract {
Mapping big_array = new Mapping();
uint256 public last;
function write(uint256 index, uint256 data) public {
big_array.write(index,data);
}
function readMap(uint256 index) public returns (uint256) {
last = big_array.map(index); // it works, i would like something like that for writeMap
return last;
}
}
```

However i had to write the function "write" because i couldn't find the right syntax to access directly Mapping.map in this manner.Do i miss something or is it just not possible ?